# How to force memory allocation in the zone DMA32 from user space

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

I'm experimenting with the `slab` allocator and I'm now interested to understand if it is possible from *user space* to "force" a new memory page to be allocated in the `DMA32` kernel zone.

I have tried with `mmap` with the `MAP_32BIT` with no luck. I have verified it using `bpftrace` that allowed me to accessory to the `zone` pointer.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: DMA32 is only used by drivers for DMA devices with 32-bit address hardware. Why would it ever be used by userspace?

Comment: I didn't know that, that's why I asked for some help

Comment: @stark if the user space want a DMA-able buffer that can be passed directly to the device it is good to have all limitations to be applied beforehand, otherwise it may end up with the bounce buffers.